Restrict sftp-user to specific directory only which is on a mounted volume
I have the following setup:
The user quack is in a chroot-jail which is on a mounted volume.
It is defined in the following way in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
Match User quack
    ChrootDirectory /sftp/quack/mnt/media0/
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

Inside the chroot directory is a directory called dump, which has the following permissions:
drwxr-xr-x 6 quack sftprestricted  4096 xx xx xx:xx dump

The directory media0 has the following permissions:
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 xx xx xx:xx media0

I want to restrict quack to the dump-directory. But as soon as I change the config by adding dump at the end of the ChrootDirectory in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config, I become unable to access it via the SFTP-User:
Read from remote host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Connection reset by peer
debug3: send packet: type 1
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
Connection closed.  
Connection closed

When I set it back to the inital chroot, everything works fine, I am able to connect and read and write to the directory media0 and its subdirectories. What am I doing wrong?

Given that the server is closing the connection – what are you seeing in the server's logs?

@grawity_u1686 This is what it says:
debian sshd[7574]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user quack(uid=1002) by (uid=0)
debian sshd[7574]: pam_env(sshd:session): deprecated reading of user environment enabled
debian sshd[7574]: User child is on pid 7631
debian sshd[7574]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user quack


The requirement for ChrootDirectory: all components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are not writable by group or others.

@KamilMaciorowski thanks! That fixed it!
